# How to run a model method in capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Suppose I have a model method

```
def self.do_something
```

How do I run this method after deploy in capistrano?  I've tried runner, I've tried making a rake task, nothing works.  Can someone provide an exemplar?

Thanks,
kevin

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the rails environment before calling your rake task in your `deploy` file, Capistrano doesn't do it.

```
run "cd #{current_path} ; RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake my:task"
```